# Questions about a Java beginners

Tags: java

```
class Employee {
    public String toString() {
        reuturn getClass().getName()
          + "[name="  + name
          + ",salary"  + salary
          + ",hireDay"  + hireDay +"]";
    }  
}  

class Manager extends Employee {
    public String toString() {
         return super.toString()
           + "[bouns=" + bouns 
           + "]"; 
    }            
}
```

****Quetion:****Now,How to do print     Manager[name=...,salary=...,hireDay=...,][bouns=...] ?

Comment: And eventually what did you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an instance of your class on which you can call `toString` method :

```
Manager m = new Manager();
...

Set the value

....
System.out.println(m.toString());

// or simply

System.out.println(m);
//this will indeed equal to call m.toString
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Manager mgr = new Manager();
```

Just use `System.out.println()` like this:

```
System.out.println("Contents of Manager's toString() --> " + mgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up constructors for Manager and Employee that initialize the name, salary, hireDay, and bouns variable.

Then you would need to create a Manager and set those variables through the constructor or a setter method.

Then you can simply do `System.out.println(manager.toString());` where manager is the name of the Manager variable you created.